# How to find 30 most frequent values in big data set?

Tags: r

Is there any function in R to find 30 most frequently occurring elements in big data set? I have data of  38 916 x 48 (columns x rows). I tried codes below and receive same answer

> *Error in table(new) : attempt to make a table with >= **2^31 elements***

```
which.max(table(new))
```

or

```
data <- na.omit(sort(table(new$"0:48"),decreasing=TRUE, na.last = TRUE)[1:30000])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your columns don't seem to make sense, you could try this:

```
library(dplyr)
new.2 <- data.frame(names = c(new))
new.2 %>% group_by(names) %>% summarise(cnt = n()) %>% arrange(desc(cnt)) %>% head(30)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't, it might be good to store your data in a `matrix`. At least on my PC using `table` and `sort` gives me the *30 most frequent values*.

```
set.seed(42)
d <- c(38916, 48)
x <- matrix(sample(1:999, prod(d), TRUE), d[2], d[1])

sort(table(x), TRUE)[1:30]
#x
#  39  121  444  134   75  455  540  786  188  882  195  824  559  982  864  230 
#2010 1999 1994 1982 1977 1975 1974 1973 1972 1969 1966 1965 1964 1964 1962 1961 
# 872  944  269  273  527  687  184  334  521  582   66  423  552  998 
#1961 1958 1957 1957 1957 1957 1956 1956 1956 1955 1954 1954 1954 1954
```

In case you have a `data.frame` it will produce the occurrences per margin, what will be large:

```
table(as.data.frame(x))
#Fehler in table(as.data.frame(x)) : 
#  Versuch eine Tabelle mit mehr als 2^31 Elementen zu erstellen
```

Her you can use `unlist`:

```
sort(table(unlist(as.data.frame(x))), TRUE)[1:30]
#  39  121  444  134   75  455  540  786  188  882  195  824  559  982  864  230 
#2010 1999 1994 1982 1977 1975 1974 1973 1972 1969 1966 1965 1964 1964 1962 1961 
# 872  944  269  273  527  687  184  334  521  582   66  423  552  998 
#1961 1958 1957 1957 1957 1957 1956 1956 1956 1955 1954 1954 1954 1954
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways of achieving what you are looking for. Here, an example of a dummy dataset:

```r
df <- data.frame(C1 = sample(LETTERS[1:26],10, replace = TRUE),
                 C2 = sample(LETTERS[1:26],10, replace = TRUE),
                 C3 = sample(LETTERS[1:26],10, replace = TRUE))

   C1 C2 C3
1   S  K  W
2   S  L  S
3   K  F  M
4   Q  A  S
5   O  K  D
6   N  T  R
7   I  F  L
8   A  L  H
9   Z  W  V
10  M  O  B
```

You can start by extracting all of elements into a single vector by doing:

```r
vec <- as.character(unlist(df))
```

Then, you can use `data.table` that is faster on large dataset to count, sort and extract top most frequent values:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(vec)
dt[, `:=`(count = .N), by = vec]
dt <- dt[order(-count),]
dt[1:10,]

    vec count
 1:   S     4
 2:   S     4
 3:   S     4
 4:   S     4
 5:   K     3
 6:   K     3
 7:   L     3
 8:   K     3
 9:   L     3
10:   L     3
```

---

An alternative `dplyr` solution using `count` and `slice` to extract top terms:

```r
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(vec) %>% 
  count(vec) %>% 
  arrange(-n) %>% 
  slice(1:10)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   vec       n
   <fct> <int>
 1 S         4
 2 K         3
 3 L         3
 4 A         2
 5 F         2
 6 M         2
 7 O         2
 8 W         2
 9 B         1
10 D         1
```